# Как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Что-то меня заклинило: "сойти с рельс" или "сойти с рельсов"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никакое это не исключение. 
Варианты "рельс" и "рельсов" современными словарями фиксируются как равноправные. 
Но в выражении "сойти с рельсов" уже усматривается нечленимость, чтобы не сказать идиоматичность. Так что в данном сочетании желательно именно "с рельсов".

Answer (score 0):

Сойти с рельсов - правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Случай исключения  - "Баллада о прокуренном вагоне":
Когда состав на скользком склоне
От рельс колёса оторвал